# Application delegate event(ex.: applicationWillTerminate) to my custom class

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplicationdelegate

I am creating one application where I have created my custom static class where I want to catch application level events like (applicationDidBecomeActive, applicationWillResignActive and applicationWillTerminate).

Say Ex: 
I want to set one variable in my custom class called : IS_ACTIVE, which is default false

```
class CustomClass {
    static var IS_ACTIVE: Bool = false;
}
```

I want to set IS_ACTIVE to true when applicationDidBecomeActive event occurs,

right now I am setting up IS_ACTIVE via "AppDelegate.swift" file where **applicationDidBecomeActive** occurs,

> but I want is **applicationDidBecomeActive** should occur in my custom
>   class.

please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: Hi @rmaddy,  It's not duplicate or same as you mentioned. because I do not want to integrate with view controller. I want to catch that event in simple custom class( which is not any controller. )

Comment: A view controller is just an example of another class. It's still the same question and solution.

Comment: Yes got it but it doesn't work out for me. any suggestion?

Comment: Not without setting your attempted code. I suggest posting a new question with your attempt to listen and respond to the notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my knowledge, you should add observer to listen app event look like this

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.appBecomeActive), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
```

And remember remove observer when your class deinit

Comment: Hi @baohung02, Thanks I tried your suggestion but not working as I am expecting. I thought this only works with controller class not custom class.

Comment: ok, default is always better :p